# Bootstrap tables do not align properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I created two tables using Bootstrap and both of them have a similar amount of content. Despite that, these two different tables do no align properly. I want the columns of these tables to be aligned properly like in MS Excel. The code and the picture displaying the problem is as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
    <h1 class="table-headers">Education</h1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">School</th>
        <th scope="col">Years</th>
        <th scope="col">Program</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Hacettepe University, Ankara</td>
        <td>2010-2014</td>
        <td>BA, Composition and Orchestral Conducting</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Istanbul Technical University</td>
        <td>2015-2020</td>
        <td>Ph.D.(c), Orchestral Conducting</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
    <h1 class="table-headers">Experience</h1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Institution</th>
        <th scope="col">Years</th>
        <th scope="col">Position</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Hacettepe University, Ankara</td>
        <td>2014-2015</td>
        <td>Intern</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Istanbul Technical University</td>
        <td>2015-2020</td>
        <td>Research Assistant</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the columns width for that:

```
table th {width: 10%}
table td {width: 30%}
```

As a side note, you [can't use headers inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11859802/6525081), instead you can use the `caption` elements and style it as you wish. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/caption) about that element.

So your tables can look something like that:

```css
table th {width: 10%}
table td {width: 30%}
table caption {font-size: 2em; caption-side: top;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
    <caption class="table-headers">Education</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">School</th>
        <th scope="col">Years</th>
        <th scope="col">Program</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Hacettepe University, Ankara</td>
        <td>2010-2014</td>
        <td>BA, Composition and Orchestral Conducting</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Istanbul Technical University</td>
        <td>2015-2020</td>
        <td>Ph.D.(c), Orchestral Conducting</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
    <caption class="table-headers">Experience</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Institution</th>
        <th scope="col">Years</th>
        <th scope="col">Position</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Hacettepe University, Ankara</td>
        <td>2014-2015</td>
        <td>Intern</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Istanbul Technical University</td>
        <td>2015-2020</td>
        <td>Research Assistant</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all content into *one*  table for that:

```css
table {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
    <h1 class="table-headers">Education</h1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">School</th>
        <th scope="col">Years</th>
        <th scope="col">Program</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Hacettepe University, Ankara</td>
        <td>2010-2014</td>
        <td>BA, Composition and Orchestral Conducting</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Istanbul Technical University</td>
        <td>2015-2020</td>
        <td>Ph.D.(c), Orchestral Conducting</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <h1 class="table-headers">Experience</h1>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Institution</th>
        <th scope="col">Years</th>
        <th scope="col">Position</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Hacettepe University, Ankara</td>
        <td>2014-2015</td>
        <td>Intern</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Istanbul Technical University</td>
        <td>2015-2020</td>
        <td>Research Assistant</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

P.S.: What you have there has nothing to to with CSS tables, but is/are regular HTML tables.

Comment: This is not valid html: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11859802/6525081

Comment: @A.Meshu I just copied and edited the code from the question, adjusting it to be *one*  table instead of two, which works. For the rest of the code, I am not responsible. So your comment should actually be a comment to the question